# Shopware 6 JEST unit test: setup failed with configuration error 'Could not locate module'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, shopware6

I try to [run a simple test](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started) with [jest in Shopware 6](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/testing/jest-admin) custom plugin application.

The test failed with configuration error "Could not locate module"

```
 FAIL  component/src/test/sum.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module @shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es/data/Criteria mapped as:
    @shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/umd$1.
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^@shopware-ag\/admin-extension-sdk\/es(.*)$/": "@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/umd$1"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

    > 1 | import Criteria from '@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es/data/Criteria';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | // eslint-disable-next-line sw-deprecation-rules/private-feature-declarations
      4 | export default Criteria;

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/data/criteria.data.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/data/index.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/shopware.ts:34:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@shopware-ag/jest-preset-sw6-admin/@tool/setup-env-for-shopware.js:8:18)
...
```

The file `@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es/data/Criteria` (*Criteria.d.ts*) is present.

```
// package.json
...
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.20.13",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@shopware-ag/jest-preset-sw6-admin": "^4.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.2.10",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.2",
    "jest": "^29.4.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.2"
  }
...
```

My [jest config](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) file:

```
const { join, resolve } = require('path');

process.env.ADMIN_PATH = resolve("../../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/");


module.exports = {
    preset: '@shopware-ag/jest-preset-sw6-admin',
    globals: {
        // adminPath: process.env.ADMIN_PATH,
        adminPath: process.env.ADMIN_PATH,
        // projectRoot: process.env.PROJECT_ROOT,
    },

    rootDir: "./component/",

    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^test(.*)$': '<rootDir>/test$1',
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js',
        "uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
    },
};
```

**Questions**

- Why does the mapping fail?
- Is there a dependency missing in my `package.json`?

I miss documentation about this.

---

**Not yet a solution here**, what I have done:

- re-setup using the [Shopware instruction](https://github.com/shopware/jest-preset-sw6-admin)
- rewrite the `jest.config.js`:

```
const ADMIN_PATH = process.env.ADMIN_PATH = resolve(
    "../../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/"
)

module.exports = {
    preset: "@shopware-ag/jest-preset-sw6-admin",
    globals: {
        adminPath: ADMIN_PATH,
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
    },
};
```

- running test: same mapping error:

```
Could not locate module
   @shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es/data/Criteria mapped as:
@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/umd$1.
```

- debug the request: the mapping error comes from this script

```
custom/plugins/MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/administration/test/node_modules/@shopware-ag/jest-preset-sw6-admin/jest-preset.js
```

What i find out, the required imported script is a `typescript` which import another `typescript`:

- `../../../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/data/index.js:2:1)`:

```
import ChangesetGenerator from './changeset-generator.data';
import Criteria from './criteria.data';
...
export default {
    ChangesetGenerator,
    Criteria,
    ...
};
```

- `../../../../../../../../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/data/criteria.data.ts:`

```
import Criteria from '@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es/data/Criteria'; // <---this import fails

// eslint-disable-next-line sw-deprecation-rules/private-feature-declarations
export default Criteria;
```

No glue if the `typescript` context is relevant, but the further required import of `js` file is imported without error

Answer (score 0):

Solution *in short*:

```
// ~/custom/plugin/myPlugin/src/Resources/app/administration/jest.config

const path = require('path');
const resolve = path.resolve;

const adminPath = process.env.ADMIN_PATH = resolve(
    "/path/to.../src/Administration/Resources/app/administration"
);

module.exports = {
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
        customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"],
    },

    preset: '\@shopware-ag/jest-preset-sw6-admin',
    globals: {
        adminPath: adminPath,
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^\@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es(.*)$': adminPath  + '/node_modules/\@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/umd$1',
        "uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
    },
    testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/test/**/*.spec.js',
    ],
};
```

Extended Answer:

I followed the poor Shopware documentation and the unmentioned Shopware Default Jest Preset (at least I couldn't find it). At this way i was guide to [install vue-test-utils](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/installation/#using-vue-test-utils-with-jest-recommended) with `npm install --save-dev @vue/test-utils`.
This command install the **newest version** of `vue-test-utils` (version 2.+), but Shopware 6 (include the actual `Version 6.5`)  [is using `"@vue/test-utils": "1.3.3"`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/7b2a7897403a1f8e7648110bd5a7f5be45f6f904/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/package.json#L57) until today. Result: Conflicts.

After installing the corresponding `vue-test-utils` and configuration [with this hint](https://github.com/shopware/jest-preset-sw6-admin#via-jestconfigjs), the tests **still don't work**:

```
...
 globals: {
        adminPath: '<file-path-to-sw6-administration>', // required, e.g. /www/sw6/platform/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration
    }
```

The right mapping should be:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
        '^\@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es(.*)$': adminPath  + '/node_modules/\@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/umd$1',
    },
```

With this configuration i was able to work.

Summary: **Be carefull using the provided Shopware documentation**.